# Silverstripe CMS Loading data into form : BootstrapForm::loadDataFrom() Link to this post

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, silverstripe

I am trying to load data into a form. I am using the bootstrap-forms module from Uncle Cheese. As I understand it I would normally call `$form->loadDataFrom(Customer::get()->byID(4));` but the bootstrap module structures the form differently.

```
//CREATE CUSTOMER FORM
public function CustomerForm() {
    return BootstrapForm::create(   
        $this,
        "CustomerForm",
        FieldList::create(
            TextField::create("Name","Name")
            TextField::create("Surname","Surname"),

            FieldList::create(
                FormAction::create("AddCustomer","Add customer")
                    ->setStyle("success")
            ),
            RequiredFields::create(array("Name","Surname","Tel1", "Address")),

            /// I think the load data method should go here but i keep getting errors
            BootstrapForm::loadDataFrom(Customer::get()->byID(4)
        )
    )
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the loadDataFrom() function outside of the form creation to pass in a DataObject for population of the fields.

**Note:** In the example below each of the arguments that are passed into BootstrapForm::create() are split into variables. This tends to make the code more readable and easy if you need to alter the form arguments at a later date.

I find this a good practice rather than trying to jam everything into the one method call.

Once the data is loaded into the form we then return the form object with:

```
return $form;
```

This makes the form available to the View layer. For example in a SilverStripe *.ss template you could include this form by putting a $CustomerForm placeholder in your mark up.

Hope it helps.

```
//CREATE CUSTOMER FORM
public function CustomerForm(){

    $fields = FieldList::create(
        TextField::create("Name","Name"),
        TextField::create("Surname","Surname")
    );

    $actions = FieldList::create(
        FormAction::create("AddCustomer","Add customer")
        ->setStyle("success")
    );

    $validator = RequiredFields::create(array("Name","Surname","Tel1", "Address"));

    $form = BootstrapForm::create($this, "CustomerForm", $fields, $actions, $validator);

    //Load your data into the form here.
    $form->loadDataFrom(Customer::get()->byID(4));

    return $form;
}
```